# Comparing part of a filename in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch, comparison

Consider this script:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%G in ("%1") do set partial_name = %%G
 if partial_name GEQ 9200 ( move I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1  L:\OSLDos\Tmp\ ) else  ( move I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1 L:\LdisOSLDos\Tmp\ ) 
ENDLOCAL
```

invoked as `thisscript 11111.9100.csv`

What I want to do is:
move the file to the correct folder, based on the second segment of the file name (9100), so if it is greater than 9200 move it to one folder and if it is not, move to another folder.

The problem seems to that the comparison does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually comparing the string `partial_name` to `9100`, not the content of the variable.

Since `p GEQ 9`, this will evaluate to true.

Also, `set partial_name = %%G` sets `partial_name`  to  `%%G` (note trailing and leading spaces).

To fix both issues this, surround the variable name with percent signs (`%`) and remove the spaces surround the eual sign (`=`):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%G in ("%1") do set partial_name=%%G
 if %partial_name% GEQ 9200 ( move I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1  L:\OSLDos\Tmp\ ) else  ( move I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1 L:\LdisOSLDos\Tmp\ )
```

Comment: You have identified and fixed one problem, but there are more :-) See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/541602/109090)

Comment: You're right. It won't work with the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Dennis identified one problem and provided a solution in his answer. But there are still other issues.

1) Your code `set partial_name = %%G` will include a trailing space in the variable name and a leading space in the value. The code should read `set partial_name=%%G`

2) Your `%1` value may already be quoted, in which case you should remove the quotes before adding your own by using `"%~1"` instead of `"%1"`.

3) Perhaps not a problem in your case, but it is generally a good idea to enclose file paths in quotes in case the name contains space or special characters.

4) I'm assuming you want to do a numeric comparison. The IF command uses almost the same rules as the SET /A command when it attempts to parse a number - Any number prefixed with 0 will be treated as hexadecimal notation. If it finds an invalid hex digit like 8 or 9, then the IF will revert to a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison.

For example `if 09 lss 8 (echo true) else echo false` returns `true`.

So if the 2nd segment of your file name has the potential to have leading zeros, then you need to do more work.

```
set "partial_name="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%G in ("%~1") do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%G") do set /a "partial_name=%%N"
  if not defined partial_name set "partial_name=0"
)
if %partial_name% GEQ 9200 (
  move "I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1" "L:\OSLDos\Tmp\"
) else (
  move "I:\rosa\transfertmp\%1" "L:\LdisOSLDos\Tmp\"
)
```

Comment: dbenham,Thank you indeed for this brilliant solution! It worked immediately. /Rolf